# if condition not working on Table column when mouse moves fast

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select table column on mouse event using jquery It works fine when user selecting the column slowly but when user selecting column fast from down word or upward direction my condition becomes fail.

```
if ($(this).find("td").eq(currentColoumn).hasClass('selected') == true) {
                    flag = false;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
```

my jsFidle is [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg58G/5/) to check it

User only can select the column upto `.selected` css found then stop dragging on column and not allowed to select the `.selected` css td.

Comment: I've tried it and it seems to work fine, it fails when your mouse slides to the neighbour columns, or when you hit the red cell. Maybe the red cell doesn't have this event binded?

Comment: how should I do for to event bind... in abouve case

Comment: I don't have time to analyse the code, it's really long. I'm just telling you my observations.

Comment: I agree with @MightyPork - this only seems to be a problem when you move across columns irrespective of the cursor speed (arguably it's just more likely to happen on a quick movement).

Comment: @gvee Yes my dear friend but can you please give me solution over it I tried all the way but not getting yet....